# Convert .mat file to image in google colab

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, mat

I'm currently trying to converting the images from a .mat file to .jpg file downloaded from this site- [BrainTumorDataset](https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/brain_tumor_dataset/1512427). All the files contained in the directory are .mat files, now I want to convert all the files in .jpg format via python for making a project: Brain Tumor Classification via CNN. I searched in StackOverflow and got a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208896/converting-mat-file-extension-image-to-jpg-via-python). But I cannot do using their code in the answer part. Here I used the code-

```
from os import path
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py
from PIL import Image
import re
import sys
from glob import glob


dir_path = path.dirname(path.abspath('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/brain tumor/New folder'))
path_to_mat_files = path.join(dir_path, "*.mat")
found_files = glob(path_to_mat_files, recursive=True)
total_files = 0


def convert_to_png(file: str, number: int):
    global total_files
    if path.exists(file):
        print(file, "already exist\nSkipping...")
    else:
        h5_file = h5py.File(file, 'r')
        png = file[:-3] + "png"
        cjdata = h5_file['cjdata']
        image = np.array(cjdata.get('image')).astype(np.float64)
        label = cjdata.get('label')[0,0]
        PID = cjdata.get('PID')
        PID = ''.join(chr(c) for c in PID)
        tumorBorder = np.array(cjdata.get('tumorBorder'))[0]
        tumorMask = np.array(cjdata.get('tumorMask'))
        h5_file.close()
        hi = np.max(image)
        lo = np.min(image)
        image = (((image - lo)/(hi-lo))*255).astype(np.uint8)
        im = Image.fromarray(image)
        im.save(png)
        os.system(f"mv {png} {dir_path}\\png_images")#make sure folder png_images exist
        total_files += 1
        print("saving", png, "File No: ", number)
        
for file in found_files:
    if "cvind.mat" in file:
        continue
    convert_to_png(file, total_files)
print("Finished converting all files: ", total_files)
```

and I got the msg :

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/brain tumor/cvind (1).mat already exist
Skipping...
Finished converting all files:  0
```

Here is my colab notebook [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l2kvysdmc_jdvxfX4Yi7tk-8HpNuAUoW#scrollTo=9yjzXv5MUkvT). and here is the dataset [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19RMNueyzQUO4nHSBuFifXJaFSJgw0B6b?usp=sharing) in my google drive. I want to convert .mat images in .jpg format. How can I do this? What should I do to convert .mat images in .jpg format?